# JQuery UI Sortable update/stop not executing code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

Here's my Javascript:

```
$(function() {
 $( "#accordion" )
  .sortable({
    axis: "y",
    handle: ".panel-heading",
    update: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('update fired');
        var categoryOrder =[];
        categoryOrder = $(".panel-heading").map(function()
        {
              return $(this).data("order");
        }) ;
        // ajax store goes here
    },
 });
});
```

I want to save the order of accordion panels according to the last place they were sorted. My plan is to build an array and use ajax to store the order referencing the information set in the data-order attribute. For some reason when I sort a panel in the DOM it does not fire the update function correctly. The console will show my `console.log('update fired')` but when I check to see the contents of the `categoryOrder` variable it returns as undefined.

When I run the same set of code in the console it builds my `categoryOrder` array as I hope it would. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

FYI, I'm using jquery 1.10.2 and jquery ui 1.11

Comment: When you say you're checking the contents of categoryOrder, where are you doing that? Could be possible that you're trying to use categoryOrder out of scope.

Comment: Would you object to something more "brute force"? http://jsfiddle.net/44GJP/1/

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code so we can see what is wrong !

Comment: Where are you setting the attribute `order`..? does jquery ui save it..? can't find any documentation on it.